# WPF resource not found

Tags: wpf, systemcolors

If I use the following in XAML I get an error:

```
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The error is:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='#FF316AC5'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you were almost right, just the wrong keys!

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 5):

You meant `HighlightColorKey`, not `HighlightColor`. The key is used with `DynamicResource` whereas the color is used only with `{x:Static}` but won't be dynamic.

Comment: You probably meant <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True"> as your trigger?

Comment: No, I wanted the DataTrigger, as it binds to Selected on my class